# How to make the corners?

Tags: chessboard

I know how to do a `4 \times 5` chessboard:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\let\boardfont\undefinedcommand
\usepackage{diagram}

\begin{document}
\setboolean{showcomputer}{false}
\setboolean{piececounter}{false}
\specialdiagnum{}
\begin{diagram}[5x4]
\pieces{}
\end{diagram}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I don't know to maker the corner.

Comment: What makes you into believing that `skak` can do it?

Comment: The skak is there because I took a previous situation. As it stands, it does not affect

Comment: Do you actually want to play chess on this boards or do you try to misuse the chess packages to draw black and white diagrams?

Comment: In this case, I want to only do the drawing on the Board

Comment: You last comment is not clear. "on the board"? Does something else will be set in this image? Please provide all information. Like this, you should do such a grid with TikZ or alike. If you want to use the diagrams, do them in a standalone, include it to your file as .pdf and [superpose](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/32245) white rectangles

Comment: off topic: please get rid of packages which do not affect in your MWE, use question-titles which will help other users of this forum as well in future (something descriptive), and explain a bit more detailed what you want, have tried, and not been able to solve. And you should go through your other posts and accept the answers as this is the way to say thank you and to close issues here.

Comment: @benedito: Looks like a `Sheldon Cooper` version of chess or the threedimensional chess - board (tower) at Star Trek Next Generation ;-)

Comment: This drawing will serve to illustrate the solution of a Mathematical problem. But, I also use to learn more about Latex.

Comment: Use tikz to create such drawings if you don't want to play chess. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168222/how-can-i-draw-a-chessboard-missing-two-diagonally-opposite-corner-squares/

Comment: Tried using the PStricks but, unfortunately, I haven't been able to do the drawing. Can anyone give me a suggestion for what I can do?

Comment: I made the drawing using TikZ, after reading the excellent  notes "A very minimal introduction to TikZ" by Professor Jacques Crémer.

Comment: @benedito In that case, perhaps you could post your solution as an answer to your question? This will enable other users to learn from what you discovered, too.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw 
    (0,0) -- (2,0) 
    (5,0)--(7,0) 
    (0,1)--(7,1)
    (0,2)--(7,2)
    (1,3)--(6,3)
    (0,5)--(7,5)
    (0,4)--(7,4)
    (0,6)--(2,6)
    (5,6) -- (7,6)
;
\draw
    (0,0) -- (0,2)
    (0,4)--(0,6)
    (1,0)--(1,6)
    (2,0)--(2,6)
    (3,1)--(3,5)
    (4,1)--(4,5)
    (5,0)--(5,6)
    (6,0)--(6,6)
    (7,0)--(7,2)
    (7,4)--(7,6)
;
\fill 
    (1,0) rectangle (2,1)
    (0,1) rectangle (1,2)
    (1,4) rectangle (2,5)
    (0,5) rectangle (1,6)
    (2,1) rectangle (3,2)
    (1,2) rectangle (2,3)
    (2,3) rectangle (3,4)
    (3,2) rectangle (4,3)
    (3,4) rectangle (4,5)
    (4,3) rectangle (5,4)
    (4,1) rectangle (5,2)
    (5,0) rectangle (6,1)
    (6,1) rectangle (7,2)
    (5,2) rectangle (6,3)
    (5,4) rectangle (6,5)
    (6,5) rectangle (7,6)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]