# How to display chessboard with missing opposite diagonal corner pieces in latex?

Tags: conditionals, chessboard

So far I have a chessboard which is displayed fully, however, I want to modify it such that it has missing opposite diagonal corner pieces, I don't mind which corner.

This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{Chess board with opposite diagonal corner pieces missing.}
\label{fig:mutilated_chessboard}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm]
    \foreach \x in {0,...,7} \foreach \y in {0,...,7}
    {
        \pgfmathparse{mod(\x+\y,2) ? "black" : "white"}
        \edef\colour{\pgfmathresult}
        \path[fill=\colour] (\x,\y) rectangle ++ (1,1);
    }
    \draw (0,0)--(0,8)--(8,8)--(8,0)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

I was thinking of adding an if statement to only run the contents of the nested for loops if the x and y values were not both equal to 0 or both equal to 8. How should I do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Hi, I will add the details no problem. My edit needs to be peer reviewed

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168222/how-can-i-draw-a-chessboard-missing-two-diagonally-opposite-corner-squares.

Answer (score 2):

Using you suggestion of some `\if`s.

It's a solution, but it's too much work for you and for Ti*k*Z to check every square. A better solution would be to draw on top of the chess board.

Also, are you aware of the [`skak`](https://ctan.org/pkg/skak) package?

You didn't specify *which* two corners, so I made the two variants:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{Chess board with opposite diagonal corner pieces missing.}
\label{fig:mutilated_chessboard}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm]
    \foreach \x in {0,...,7} \foreach \y in {0,...,7}
    {
        \pgfmathparse{mod(\x+\y,2) ? "black" : "white"}
        \edef\colour{\pgfmathresult}
% This one for the bottom-left and top-right corners
        % \ifnum\x=\y
        %   \ifnum\x=7
        %     \def\colour{black}
        %   \else\ifnum\x=0
        %     \def\colour{black}
        %   \fi\fi
        % \fi
% % % % % %
% And this one for the top-left and bottom-right corners
        \ifnum\x=\numexpr\y-7
          \ifnum\x=0
            \def\colour{white}
          \fi
        \fi
        \ifnum\y=\numexpr\x-7
          \ifnum\y=0
            \def\colour{white}
          \fi
        \fi
% % % % % %
        \path[fill=\colour] (\x,\y) rectangle ++ (1,1);
    }
    \draw (0,0)--(0,8)--(8,8)--(8,0)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think that skak is suitable here. Imho the OP is trying to draw squares. "chessboard" describes the geometry and not the game.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree. But told him just in case :)

Comment: Cheers, solved my problem!

Comment: I think those `\numexpr` will keep expanding until they run into either `\def` or something `\path` expands to. I recommend either appending `\relax` after the `-7`s or swapping the order of those two `\ifnum` so that the `=` terminates the `\numexpr`.