# How can I draw a chessboard with two corners removed?

Tags: chessboard

I  am trying to draw a chessboard like this

[image]

I used this question [To draw a chessboard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133332/to-draw-a-chessboard) and I got this board. How can I get the board in the first image?

[image]

Comment: You can probably adapt https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370930/250119 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358694/250119

Comment: Also almost same as [diagrams - How can I draw a chessboard missing two diagonally opposite corner squares? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168222/how-can-i-draw-a-chessboard-missing-two-diagonally-opposite-corner-squares?rq=1) except for the alternative coloring

Comment: Instead of removing corners, use \phantom{...} to make them disappear.